# Connection reset - issue getting in Spring Boot application while trying to connect to AWS RDS using TCPS connection

Tags: java, oracle, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I am trying to connect to Oracle RDS server of AWS by using TCPS connection, below is the code snippet I am using to connect

```
try{
OracleConnectionPoolDataSource ds = null;
ds = new OracleConnectionPoolDataSource();
Properties keyStoreProp = new Properties();
                keyStoreProp.put("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "./clientkeystore.jks");
                keyStoreProp.put("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "JKS");
                keyStoreProp.put("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "keyStorePasssword");

                ds.setConnectionProperties(keyStoreProp);

Properties cacheConProp = new Properties();
cacheConProp.setProperty("MinLimit", "25");
cacheConProp.setProperty("MaxLimit", "5");
                cacheConProp.setProperty("InitialLimit", "3");
                cacheConProp.setProperty("InactivityTimeout", "1800");
                cacheConProp.setProperty("AbandonedConnectionTimeout", "900");
                cacheConProp.setProperty("PropertyCheckInterval", "60");
                cacheConProp.setProperty("ValidateConnection", "true");
                cacheConProp.setProperty("ConnectionWaitTimeout", "120");

                ds.setConnectionProperties(cacheConProp);

ds.setDatabaseName(dbName);
ds.setUser(dataUserName);
ds.setPassword(dataPassword);
ds.setURL(tcpsConnectionUrl);
ds.setNetworkProtocol("TCPS");

if (ds.getConnection() != null) {
 LOG.info("CONNECTION_SUCCESSFUL");
} else {            
 LOG.error("CONNECTION_FAILED");
}

} catch (SQLException e) {
 LOG.error("CONNECTION_FAILED";
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and the I have created clientkeystore.jks file by following the steps mentioned as "Setting Up an SSL Connection Over JDBC" in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.Oracle.Options.SSL.html#Appendix.Oracle.Options.SSL.TLS doc file, but getting Connection reset issue.

Can anyone please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: I assume you've added the RDS SSL Certs?

Comment: Yes @DarrenForsythe I have used the RDS SSL cert only

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using OracleConnectionPoolDataSource? You can use OracleDataSource and check out the [DataSourceForJKS.java](https://github.com/oracle/oracle-db-examples/blob/master/java/jdbc/ConnectionSamples/DataSourceForJKS.java) sample for reference.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, let me test with the sample code, but one thing is that do I need to provide both keystore and truststore file, if it is so then how to create these two file from https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-ca-2015-root.pem file in java keytool.